# Select multiple tables when one table is empty in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to do

```
SELECT * FROM a, b
```

However, it doesn't return anything if one of the tables is empty. How do I make it so it returns 'a' even if the other one is empty?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

You are using the form of `INNER JOIN` which results with x*y records, so if 1 of them has 0 rows then x*0 = 0.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using two tables in the `from` clause is functionally equivalent to a `cross join`:

```
select  *
from    A
cross join
        B
```

This returns a row of A for every row in B.  When B is empty, the result is empty too.  You can fix that by using a `left join`.  With a `left join`, you can return rows even if one of the tables is empty. For example:

```
select  * 
from    A
left join  
        B
on      1=1
```

As the condition `1=1` is always true, this is just like a `cross join` except it also works for empty tables.

Comment: FYI, "In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other)"

Comment: @Imre L: Interesting.  It's probably still clearer to use `cross join`  by convention if there is no `on` clause, even if MySQL allows `inner join` for the same purpose!

Comment: Yes. I personally prefer to omit words `INNER` and `CROSS`, etc. But i dont like using inline CROSS JOIN  when there is some conditions used on joined table.

Comment: does not work if I use a WHERE clause on table A that returns 0 rows (the table is not empty). I tried also switching between tables A and B, but still no records are returned

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Will return everything from a even if b is empty.

Comment: You've assumed there are fields to join with, there may be no common field. Without common fields this can't work. See the ON 1=1 in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a left join.

Like this

```
SELECT *
FROM A
 LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Then you receive the rows in A and the respective row in B if exists.

Comment: You've assumed there are fields to join with, there may be no common field. Without common fields this can't work. See the ON 1=1 in the answer. That's the key to the whole question, joining empty sets without common fields.

Comment: Yes, you're right, in that case a cross join is required or the condition 1=1 which is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

in this example id is just example name for join key

Comment: You've assumed there are fields to join with, there may be no common field. Without common fields this can't work. See the ON 1=1 in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The query mentioned above display join of both tables if a contain 2 record and b contain 7 records it displays 7*2 = 14 records. In your case one of the table is empty( with 0 records), it will not display any data. If still you want to display data and **tables are not having any relationship**, you need to check if count of both tables greater that 0. Otherwise display records from only one table which is not empty.