# How to select two tables in one query when second is empty (harder, not order task)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables in MySQL: t1 AND t2.
The structure is something like that:

```
t1.aa    t2.az
t1.bb    t2.zz
t1.cc    t2.aa
         t2.dz
```

Now, I need to get something like:

```
result: t1.aa = 'value', t2.dz = 'value';
```

BUT:

1) second table (t2) is possibly just empty

2) In my query "WHERE" statement like this:

```
WHERE t1.aa=t2.aa AND t2.zz=345
```

So, if second table is really empty I need get something like this:

```
result: t1.aa = 'value', t2.dz = null;
```

Thanks.

P.S. we have other answers like [Select multiple tables when one table is empty in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171276/select-multiple-tables-when-one-table-is-empty-in-mysql) , but my problem is in "WHERE" statement..

My tables are:

Table t1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `aa` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bb` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Table t1 Data

```
INSERT INTO `t1` (`aa`, `bb`, `cc`) VALUES
(1, 'varchar in bb', 'cc varchar');
```

Table t2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `az` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zz` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `aa` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `dz` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`az`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Table t2 Data is null

Comment: I would show you the query, but the comment "Think you are genius? Solve this to prove it." is putting me off... read up on LEFT JOIN... apparently you didnt' get it from the article you reference...

Comment: Sorry for that, I will remove it as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

I am not a genius, but I read mysql documentacion

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/#manual

Use JOIN ( I did not Test it) you need to prove it.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.aa == t2.aa WHERE t2.zz = 345
```

Comment: Without DDL statements, and  real data or even sqlfiddle.com/. It is impossible to test your cases. At least I hack your computer and extract the data (unfortunately, I am not a hacker) However; this is the SQL query you need to do what you are asking for

Comment: can you please provide a DDL statements, real data and/or sqlfiddle? How can I test your issue without having your real data and table structure

Comment: If second table is really empty I need get something like this:

result: t1.aa = 'value', t2.dz = null;

But in result I just get nothing..

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll create a sqlfiddle

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `aa` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bb` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `t1` (`aa`, `bb`, `cc`) VALUES
(1, 'varchar in bb', 'cc varchar');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `az` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zz` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `aa` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `dz` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`az`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: I am out of home now, I will reply, as soon as i get there. Thank you for the DDL statements. I will appreciate real data too.

Comment: It has real data (has INSERT INTO ...). But as you will find out, your query return 0 rows. (also, you should use t1.aa = t2.aa instead of "==").
Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Lea Tano, we were close.

The right query is:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.aa=t2.aa AND zz=345
```

As you can see, there is no need in "WHERE" statement. This role has inherited by "ON ... AND ...".

Thank all for any help.

And Lea Tano, mostly.

Comment: Cheers!! I will recommend you next time when you have a MYSQL question to include sqlfiddle or the DDL, so people can easily check their answer against your real data. Also, I recommend you to do NOT use sentences like `Think it's easy? Then just solve it.` or `Think you are genius? Solve this to prove it.` We are not genius, we want to help people. That is all. I am glad that you found it yourself.

Comment: And yes, you are right, your answer is the correct answer.

Comment: Sentences like `"Think you are genius?..."` - I really don't understand why I've used these. It's really bad sentences. We are not on TV or other public show - it's recommend to use corresponding sentences.
Sorry for that. I won't make this mistake another time.