# mysql empty result set when i know data is in my tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 tables that i am running a SELECT statement against, when all of the tables have data in them it all works fine but if only 1 table has data in it i get zero results? how can i get the query to work when not all tables are populated with data.  proper scratiching my head now, please help!

```
SELECT admins.username, round1.player, round1.round1_score, 
     round2.player, round2.round2_score,
     round3.player, round3.round3_score, 
     round4.player, round4.round4_score, 
     round5.player, round5.round5_score 
FROM `admins`, `round1`, `round2`, `round3`, `round4`, `round5` 
WHERE admins.username <> 'admin' 
     AND admins.username = round1.player 
     AND admins.username = round2.player 
     AND admins.username = round3.player 
     AND admins.username = round4.player 
     AND admins.username = round5.player 
GROUP BY admins.username
```

Comment: Please show us your php code

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor schema design

Comment: thanks @Strawberry. what would be a good scema for this scenario? i am new to this technology and havent been blessed with having the luxury of formal training or a full time job working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `admins` table is the master table?  You need to use `outer joins` instead:

```
SELECT a.username, r1.player, r1.round1_score, 
       r2.player, r2.round2_score, r3.player, r3.round3_score, 
       r4.player, r4.round4_score, r5.player, r5.round5_score 
FROM `admins` a
    LEFT JOIN `round1` r1 ON a.username = r1.player
    LEFT JOIN `round2` r2 ON a.username = r2.player
    LEFT JOIN `round3` r3 ON a.username = r3.player
    LEFT JOIN `round4` r4 ON a.username = r4.player
    LEFT JOIN `round5` r5 ON a.username = r5.player,
WHERE a.username <> 'admin' 
GROUP BY a.username
```

I'm not sure you really need the `group by`, in general it's used with aggregation (or sometimes to get `distinct` records).

Comment: this works a treat, thanks.  i did look briefly at JOINs but couldnt get my head around the logic, it makes a bit more sense now in this context.

Comment: @Conokia -- no problem, here's a good post on the different types of joins: blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: excellent link for understanding joins, with your answer and this link joins seem less intimidating to newbies like me - cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way your query is, is like using `inner join` so basically if one table has no data you get 0 results. You need to change your query using `left` join.

Answer (score 0):

try to inner join or cross join tables to get an answer i think it will works
you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171276/select-multiple-tables-when-one-table-is-empty-in-mysql) or [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=57823)

Answer (score 0):

you are connecting 5 tables

> `admins`, `round1`, `round2`, `round3`, `round4`, `round5`

this is a INNER JOIN and you have only common data

if you want data even your table on right side is empty you can use a LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT admins.username, round1.player, round1.round1_score, 
 round2.player, round2.round2_score,
 round3.player, round3.round3_score, 
 round4.player, round4.round4_score, 
 round5.player, round5.round5_scoreFROM (((((`admins` left join `round1` on admins.username = round1.player) 
    left join `round2` on admins.username = round2.player)
    left join `round3` on admins.username = round3.player)
    left join `round4` on admins.username = round4.player)
    left join `round5` on admins.username = round5.player)
    WHERE admins.username <> 'admin' 
    GROUP BY admins.username
```