# Select mysql returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT 
  lp - prev_close_price AS ch,
  (lp - prev_close_price) / prev_close_price AS chp,
  short_name,
  exchange,
  description,
  lp,
  IFNULL(ask, 0) AS ask,
  IFNULL(bid, 0) AS bid,
  IFNULL(ask - bid, 0) AS spread,
  IFNULL(open_price, prev_close_price) AS open_price,
  IFNULL(high_price, prev_close_price) AS high_price,
  IFNULL(low_price, prev_close_price) AS low_price,
  prev_close_price,
  volume
FROM
  metaTQEjY,
  lpTQEjY,
  askTQEjY,
  bidTQEjY,
  open_todayTQEjY,
  highlowTQEjY,
  prevcloseTQEjY;
```

It returns 0 rows, while all the tables definitely have values.

then I tried this

```
SELECT 
  prevcloseTQEjY.prev_close_price
FROM
  metaTQEjY,
  lpTQEjY,
  askTQEjY,
  bidTQEjY,
  open_todayTQEjY,
  highlowTQEjY,
  prevcloseTQEjY;
```

still 0 rows. But

```
SELECT 
  prevcloseTQEjY.prev_close_price
FROM
  prevcloseTQEjY;
```

Return the prev_close_price correctly. Why is it so?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you list all your tables in a FROM clause, it produces the Cartesian product of those tables. [This link is additional info on the Cartesian product of two tables](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

This is fine if you are selecting *specific data you know is there*. However, if one of those tables is empty, the Cartesian product will return an empty set.

Here is a SQL fiddle of this: [Three tables, one is empty](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95520ac/2)

As you can see, there are three tables, I have selected a value from one table, but because my FROM statement has all three tables, including an empty one, there is no data to select from, and so it returns 0 rows.

However in this example: [Two tables with data only](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95520ac/3)

I have selected the same column, but my FROM statement has only the tables with data, which returns rows as expected.

There are numerous ways to fix your query, one such method may be using a left join as described in this answer: [Select multiple tables when one table is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171276/select-multiple-tables-when-one-table-is-empty-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7):

You are performing cartesian product of these tables. You get an empty set if one of them is empty.

Comment: How about this? SELECT prevcloseTQEjY.prev_close_price 
from metaTQEjY,lpTQEjY,askTQEjY,bidTQEjY, open_todayTQEjY, highlowTQEjY, prevcloseTQEjY; It also produces no result but prev_close_price is definitely not empty

Comment: If you have AT LEAST 1 empty table in from list, your result set will be empty (it's like you are "multiplying" your dataset by 0)

Comment: @AlexanderHo one of the tables from the `metaTQEjY,lpTQEjY,askTQEjY,bidTQEjY, open_todayTQEjY, highlowTQEjY, prevcloseTQEjY` set is empty. We are speaking about empty TABLEs, not about empty attribute values.